# Does St. Gertrude's prayer have any (semi-)official standing in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, saint

I'd like to know if there was any official or unofficial statement given by the Roman Catholic Church on the [St. Gertrude's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gertrude_the_Great) prayer that saves 1000 souls from purgatory?

Is there even any record from her biography that she received this prayer and information that the prayer has this power?

[Source](http://www.catholic.org/saints/saint.php?saint_id=424)

Comment: @BearinaStudebaker: a statement from Vatican that is not part of the teaching. Some type of a comment made by pope or other bishops residing there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prayers that are supposed to automatically release souls from purgatory are ["declared to be apocryphal" (i.e. false) and are prohibited, according to the Acts of the Holy See 32 p.243, as promulgated by Pope Leo XIII.](http://www.olrl.org/pray/apocryphal.shtml)

> Reiicienda sunt folia, et libelli, in quibus promittitur fidelibus unam alteramve precem recitantibus liberatio unius vel plurium animarum a Purgatorio : et Indulgentiae quae dictae promissioni adiici solent ut apocryphae habendae sunt.

Translation

> The leaflets and booklets which promise the faithful that they will free one or more souls from Purgatory by the recitation of some prayer or another are to be rejected : and the Indulgences which are wont to be attached to the said promise are to be held as apocryphal.